# How do I swap two integers in an array, where my method takes in two integers and an array from main?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, integer, program-entry-point

I call my swap method in main, but it doesn't change anything. What am I doing wrong?

```
public static void main(String[] args){


    int mainArr[] = new int[20];

    for(int i = 0; i<mainArr.length; i++){
    swapper(3, 14, mainArr);
    System.out.print(i + mainArr[i] + " ");
    }
}


public static void swapper (int a, int b, int[] mainArr){
    int t = mainArr[a];
    mainArr[a] = mainArr[b];
    mainArr[b] = t;
}
```

My code yields

```
0, 1,  2, 3,...19
```

in normal ascending order, where I want it to swap the 4th and 15th element.

Comment: are a,b integers to swap or the indices of your main array?

Comment: Off topic -> Why are you invoking your swapper from inside a loop?

Comment: I want a and b to swap in the array

Comment: Not off topic... if he performs the swap an even number of times, he gets back the original array. When he prints the 4 value it would be 4, when he prints the 15th it should be 4 again.

Comment: @RohitJain where should it be invoked then?

Comment: Code provided doesn't put anything in array so you're printing `i+0`

Comment: @perldog93: I'd assume you want it to happen once, before you print the array, right?

Comment: @RC that is even a better catch... :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move the method call: -

```
swapper(3, 14, mainArr);
```

outside your for loop. Since, if your loop runs `even` number of times, it will not affect 
the array.

Also, you need to initialize your array first, before actually swapping the elements. That you would need to do before invoking `swapper`.

```
for(int i = 0; i<mainArr.length; i++){
    mainArr[i] = i;
}

swapper(3, 14, mainArr);

for(int i = 0; i<mainArr.length; i++){
    System.out.print(i + mainArr[i] + " ");
}
```

Comment: also fill out the array with values. He has empty array

Comment: @shevchik. Yeah added that part.

Comment: @RC. How exactly? If the swapping method is correct, this will work. I haven't seen the logic though.

Comment: @RohitJain there is nothing to swap only `0`s

Comment: @RC. That part I assume OP has considered. He has to fill the array. Even then I have edited the answer to fulfil your dream.

Comment: @RohitJain thanks for correcting your answer, now it's OK if someone comes by later (PS: I never had a doubt on the OP swap)

Comment: @RC. That's perfectly fine to have complete answer here. But I  would assume that if someone comes over and sees the code, he should assume that the array is pre-filled. But still its fine to complete it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18538/discussion-between-rc-and-rohit-jain)

Comment: @RC. Sorry but I can't chat now. Its already too late. Time to sleep. :)

Comment: Ok this now prints out 0 2 4 17 8 10 12 14 16 18 20 22 24 26 17 30 32 34 36 38, so now I am confused.

Comment: This works when I changed i to 1 in the system output. Thank you @RohitJain.

Answer (score 1):

Writing the code as so:

```
int mainArr[] = new int[20];  

for(int i =0; i <mainArr.length;i++)  
{  
    mainArr[i]=i;
}  

swapper(3,14,mainArr);
```

will resolve the issue.  The problem was you happened to be calling swap an even number of times, so it had a total effect of nothing.

Comment: Almost correct but the problem was array filling, not number of swaps ;)

Comment: @RC.. If you see the code correctly, the problem was actually number of swaps. If the number of swaps is even. how do you think that will affect the array.??

Comment: @RC. actually it wasn't the array filling, since OP gave the output he was receiving, OP happened to post the wrong code example.  The fundamental issue is the even number of swaps, go try it out.

Comment: @Woot4Moo `System.out.print(i + mainArr[i] + " ");` notice the `i +` :)

Answer (score 0):

You are calling swapper the same number of times as there are elements in your array.

- If the array has a even length, nothing will change
- If the array has a odd length, it will change

Comment: So where do you suggest I place it?

Comment: @perldog93 after the loop, or have no loop. Why do you need a loop?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class swapInt
{ 
public static void main(String args[])
{


swap(new int[]{2,3,5,6,8},1,3);


}
public static void swap(int[]a,int i,int j)
{
    int temp=a[i];
    a[i]= a[j];
    a[j]=temp;
    for(int b=0;b<a.length;b++)
    {

    System.out.println(a[b]);
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Please don't just add code to your answer with no explanation.